# Can CSRF Be Circumvented By JSONP

Tags: jsonp, csrf, csrf-protection

I'm very new to CSRF protection so please excuse if I make poor assumptions or if I'm missing something, but I'd like to make sure I'm doing all I can to prevent CSRF. From my research so far, I've found the following:

1. CSRF can be thwarted (and is probably best thwarted) by placing a nonce parameter within the request body of all HTML POSTs, *only* using POSTs to modify data, and on the server side verify the token is valid before processing the request.
2. A malicious website can send requests to my site (thwarted by the nonce), but they can't read responses because of same-origin policies in place on browsers. Assuming that someone is using a secure browser, a malicious site cannot GET a page from my site using AJAX, read the nonce, and use it for themselves.
3. Script tags are not bound by same-origin policies in most (possibly any) browsers and can therefore allow for content to be read from other sites.

When I got to point 3 I decided to try to get at HTML content in Chrome using JSONP; I opened up my console (with a page not from localhost) and ran the following code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8080/my-app/",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonp: "alert"
}).done(function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

What I received in the console window was the this:

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html

As far as I can tell the browser is essentially telling me that it received the content, proceeded to parse the response, but stopped because the type was not application/json. So finally, my question is, can this be compromised? Even though the browser failed to parse the response as JSON, it does have the response. Is there a way that this response could be parsed as HTML, grab my CSRF nonce, and compromise the protections I'm trying to enforce? It would seem to me (and I hope this to be true) that browsers will not allow this, just like they don't allow cross domain requests in the first place for basically all other communication, and that's what we as developers are relying upon (in addition to same-origin policies) to protect our sites. Is my thinking correct?